# MySQL skipped a row when inserting new record

Tags: database, mysql

The problem was that mysql was running high on CPU on our server and that lasted for about 15 minutes. In that time some of the data that were coming to server were not being inserted into db but transaction committed.

After restarting mysql problem was resolved.

So this means that even though transaction committed there were no new rows in the table. The evidence for this is auto-incremented primary key that should looked like this:

```
100
101
102
```

But currently is like this:

```
100
102
```

So the record 101 was missing and its skipped.

Now i need to find some kind of log for that record if that exists.

I tried in `mysqldump log` but there are no records there. Record 101 is still missing.

I need to find a way to recreate that transaction and do it again.

Has anyone had any similar problems?

Code looks basically like this:

```
$db->autocommit(FALSE);

$sql = "INSERT INTO t (amount, datetime) VALUES ($amount, '$datetime')";
$db->query($sql);

$id = $db->insert_id;
$sql = "INSERT INTO tr (id, log) VALUES ($id, '$log')";
$db->query($sql);

$db->autocommit(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The transaction was most likely aborted after the sequence had incremented already. This is not a problem from the database perspective: An auto incremented column is not required to have all ids sequentially in there. From a code/user perspective this should also not be a problem. If your code requires continuous ids (lets say for auditing purposes), you will have to implement a system for that yourself. If you do not require that, then just run the transaction again. That will then create id 103 (in your case).

Comment: Basically the problem was that client got response from server that everything is OK and he got his ticket. But that ticket is not on server and it doesn't exist. So I don't need sequential ids i just said that skipped ids are the evidence that mysql skipped a row when inserting and it didn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: It sounds like your code did not check a transaction state: Can you add the code executing this transaction?

Comment: I updated my question with code but i don't know if this helps its pretty basic stuff

Comment: Ok, I agree: Pretty basic. This however should have returned an error: The set transaction boundaries are consistent with the missing 101 id. The error is never caught so it might be logged in your web server logs or not logged at all. Add `try - catch` logic to log the errors is my only advice.